# Div with background image not displayed / height ignored

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a header similar to this one: http://themes.tf/preview/?momentum

I've set a height but the div still won't get displayed and the content slips to the top. 
How can I fix this?

The css is:

```
.header {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
    height:688px;
}


.bg-img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

This is the html:

```
    <div class="header bg-img" style="background-image: url('img/xlheader_s.jpg');">

        <img src="img/schwager-baubetruung_logo.png" id="logo" alt="schwager baubetreuung logo">

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Startseite</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Über uns</a></li>
            <li><a href="arbeitsablauf.html">Unsere Arbeit</a></li>
            <li><a href="galerie.html">Galerie</a></li>
            <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here you can see the live version: http://suitsncats.de/index_copy.html

If you go to the index page you can see my previous attempt that worked but had a static header image.

Comment: Do you want sticky header? if yes then check https://jsfiddle.net/elcreador419/xJXZr/

Comment: Don't know if it's the only problem, but in the example you linked, the "header" style is defined for an ID in your css (#header) and used as a class in your html.

Comment: You'r targeting an id of header in your CSS (#header) where as you need to target the class (.header).

Comment: remove `position:absolute` css prop for `nav` and `#logo`

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into the source on your website and encountered two issues:

You've used an id selector (`#header`) instead of class selector (`.header`) in your `style_copy.css` and there's also a syntax error in it (no `;` after the `height` declaration)

```
#header {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    height:668px
    z-index:1;
}

/* should become: */

.header {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    height:668px; /* <--- note ; */
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your live version, I've checked out your CSS file `style_copy.css` and noticed that you tell the CSS to look for `#header` even though in the HTML you're using `.header`.

You also forget the `;` after the `height` declaration.

**Solution:**

Change this in the live version's CSS:

```
#header {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    height:668px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

To this:

```
.header {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    height:668px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I looked into your source at live website, try following solution:

```
<div class="header bg-img" style="background-image: url('img/xlheader_s.jpg');">
            <img src="img/schwager-baubetruung_logo.png" id="logo" alt="schwager baubetreuung logo">

        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Startseite</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Über uns</a></li>
            <li><a href="arbeitsablauf.html">Unsere Arbeit</a></li>
            <li><a href="galerie.html">Galerie</a></li>
            <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

and CSS:

```
.header {
    position: static;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

nav {
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
    z-index: 2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Not exactly how you wanted, but one step closer.